# How to run several sequential MATCH functions

Tags: excel, match, libreoffice

I have a task to build a company's organogram. So, there's a list of Departments (A,B,C, column A) with their internal codes (column C), staff members (column A) and the total number of employees in each Department (TOTAL). I need to create a second table with the list of all Departments and number of employees in each.

What I did to create the list of Departments (Column F):

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH(1;(B:B=1)*(C:C="000 000 001");0))
```

In order to calculate the sum of employees I used the function:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"=*TOTAL*";C:C;"000 000 001")
```

Inventing this functions I made a workaround, by trying to find matches between the title of Department and its quantity (potentially there may be two or more Departments C) - marked in red, as well as I added the code to the TOTAL raw to find match for the calculation of the subtotals.

How to make it possible to get rid of these workarounds? I mean, in the first formula not to count the column B, and in the second formula not duplicate the Code close to the TOTAL?

Workarounds are temporary solutions. Let me add, that I need legacy compatibility with LibreOffice and OnlyOffice, so preferably no dynamic arrays, and functions like XLOOKUP, FILTER etc.
[image: example]

Comment: I would use the code better: 1st 3 digits to define the company, 2nd 3 digits to define the position and 3rd 3 digits to define the number. Also remove the spaces then mid() can get any part and compare to a value. Then countif() or countifs() will do.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Cannot remove spaces... This is fixed standard. The thing is that the structure is much more complicated (there are subdepartments, independent units) etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, set this up and you can edit / improve based on what you have to work with.

[image]

A custom format for the 9 digit code may work...

Edit to show use of custom formatting:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks. I cannot change anything (the format should stay the same) apart of marked in gray that I've made by myself in order to calculate the proper sum.